# jquery disabled state not triggering appropriately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

In this case, I two two drop down select elements that correspond to two separate div containers. When the user selects an option in the first select element, that specific value is changed to disabled true in the corresponding div. To provide a better visual of the problem, I have attached two images of the particular section.

The first image reveals the initial state of the select elements. The "Select a Standard" element corresponds to the "My Energy Standards" div, and the "Select Period" corresponds to the "My Study Periods" div.

[image]

**PROBLEM**

The issue arises when I chose a period from the select dropdown (anywhere from 1 to 40). Ideally if I select 1 year, the first check box in "My Study Periods" div should be disabled. However doing this results in 2003 being disabled. However, if i select any year greater than 4, it works as you would expect.

I have included the code sections that correspond with each section.

**CODE**

```
    //Select a Standard Code section
$("#baselineResidentialStandardYear").change(function () {
    standardValue = $("#baselineResidentialStandardYear").val();
    console.log(standardValue);
    //if (standardValue == $("#" + standardValue).attr('id') && $('#' + standardValue).hasClass("standard")) {
    //    $('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', true);
    //    $("#standards").find('input[type=checkbox]').not('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', false);
    //}
    if ($('#' + standardValue).hasClass("standard")) {
        if (standardValue == $('#' + standardValue).attr('id')) {
            $('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', true);
            $('#standards').find('input[type=checkbox]').not('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }
});

//Select Period code
$("#baselineResidentialStudyPeriod").change(function () {
    period = $("#baselineResidentialStudyPeriod").val();
    console.log(period);
    //if (period == $('#' + period).attr('id') && $('#' + period).hasClass("studyPeriod")) {
    //    console.log("test");
    //    $('#' + period).attr('disabled', true);
    //    $("#years").find('input[type=checkbox]').not('#' + period).attr('disabled', false);
    //}

    $('#years').find('input[class=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("studyPeriod")) {
            $('#' + period).attr('disabled', true);
            $('#years').find('input[type=checkbox]').not('#' + period).attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

I am not quite sure why this faulty interaction is taking place even though I am using a .find method

**IMP NOTE**

The checkbox elements in "My Energy Standards" div have a value attribute from 1 to 4.
The checkbox elements in "My Study Periods" div have a value attribute from 1 to 40.

I have to maintain this because this information will be used to retrieve more supplemental information from a database.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are wanting to achieve, but see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r56c2me/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make this...

```
$('#' + standardValue).attr('disabled', true);
```

and this...

```
$('#' + period).attr('disabled', true);
```

into...

```
$('#standards #' + standardValue).attr('disabled', true);
```

and...

```
$('#years #' + period).attr('disabled', true);
```

respectively.

Your other problem is that this might fail on some browsers as you are using duplicate IDs. You should change those IDs to classes. Having more than one id="1", etc. is bad practice.